# htaccess is not working for files

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have upgraded our apache version from 2.2 to 2.4. Now we are facing issues with htaccess file. I have added garbage data in htaccess file. Now it works like this:

```
1) http://example.com:8080/ : 500 internal error 
2) http://example.com:8080/index.php : showing the content of index.php file.
2) http://example.com:8080/login.php : File not found 
3) http://example.com:8080/phpinfo.php : showing the content
```

Now I am not getting understand what is the issue. htaccess is not working for files. It is working only for root. Apache configuration content:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080> 
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/site/shadow-site/$1
  UseCanonicalName On
  loglevel emerg

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/site/shadow-site
  <directory "/var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/">
    options followsymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </directory>
  ErrorLog /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/logs/siteerror_log
</virtualhost>
```

**Edit 1:**
I have just noticed that htaccess is working for images, CSS and JS files. Looks like its not working for php files only.

Comment: Sorry Im confused. You said its not working for files, but in the first block you state it works for index.php and phpinfo.php. Also, please clarify what you mean when you say it only works for "root"?

Comment: htaccess is not working for files. As per my code(garbage code in htaccess file), no files should work. Like login.php and phpinfo.php should also show 500 internal error. But it is showing the content of the files.

Comment: Hmm, still not sure I understand, BUT if you recently upgraded your apache version, it is possible that the apache config file was changed as well. It might have reset/removed the ability to override the htaccess file in lower subdirectories. DO you know how to check for that ?

Comment: Yes, I know that. I have pasted the content of Apache configuration file. I have also noticed one more thing. htaccess is working for images, js and css as well. Its not working only for .php files :)

Comment: Aha :-) The line starting with ProxyPassMatch is sending all of your PHP files to fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/site/shadow-site/$1 (where $1 is the path part of the original url). Not knowing your setup that's as far as I can help (sorry). All I can suggest is to try to (a) increase the log level to log everything and check the files; and (b) comment out that line and see what changes. Good luck.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your comment. I'll check it with Server Guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer of my question. It was because of ProxyPassMatch. I changed ProxyPassMatch line from :

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/site/shadow-site/$1
```

To:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(index\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/example-test-apache-24/site/shadow-site/$1
```

Now it works fine for me :)